# How to change iconbox title in MWM?

Tags: window-manager, motif

I am using the Motif Window Manager as my desktop.

Motif allows many settings to be adjusted in ~/.Xdefaults. I have a lot of settings, which are confirmed to work here, such as changing the color.

One setting which I strangely cannot get to work is changing the iconbox's window title. Adding `Mwm*useIconBox: True` to ~/.Xdefaults allows the iconbox to appear, but it displays the default title "iconbox". According to the manual, there are two settings, `Mwm*iconBoxTitle` and `Mwm*iconBoxName`, one of which I believe should allow the title to be changed, but I cannot get either to work.

Preferably, I'd like the iconbox to display the day's date as its title, so that real estate on screen has some use.

How can I get the `Mwm*iconBoxTitle` option to work?

I've tried many different combinations of commands in the ~.Xdefaults file, such as:

```
Mwm*iconBoxTitle: my title
Mwm*iconBoxTitle(my title)
Mwm*iconBoxTitle: "my title"
```

I've found sample screenshots of different OSes running MWM confirming that the iconbox window title can be changed. I've also found a few sample ~/.Xdefaults files using these `Mwm*iconBoxTitle` commands, yet copying this code to my own ~.Xdefaults did not result in any title changes.

How can I change the window title of the Motif Window Manager's iconbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several random attempts for the title I found the solution (unless in my case the following works)

Use `Mwm*title:` instead of `Mwm*iconBoxTitle:`. Maybe it's a bug or the documentation is not updated. Also I'm not sure if `Mwm*title` can change the title on some windows, I don't think so, because I opened several applications and the title are not affected.

[image: enter image a here]

I tested on Ubuntu (server) and all seems to work correctly. Hopefully this also works for you.

**Note:** When you change the title in `~/.Xdefaults` you have to restart the **MWM** or if that doesn't work try to log-out and log-in again in your Window Manager.